# How do I get both my columns into a Bar Graph?

Tags: r, matrix, plot, graph, ggplot2

I printed a matrix and I have two columns which I wish to get into a bar graph and I don't know how. When I tried it, it used the whole matrix as the X value. Here is my code

```
smoke <- matrix(c(53,42,40,40,39,34,34,30,28,24,22,21,20,16,'A','A','A','B','A','A','A','A','B','A','C','B','B', 'B'),nrow=14, ncol = 2)
colnames(smoke) <- c("NumberofBooks","Grade")
smoke <- as.table(smoke)
smoke
```

Any help into plotting the numbers against the letters would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How exactly do you want to structure your bar graph? A, B and C along the x-axis, and the y-axis as the average number of books?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the plot you want to create? (Excel for example)

Comment: Yes a bar graph with the letter grades as the X axis and the number of books as the y-axis.

Comment: Making a matrix of both numbers and strings will coerce everything to character. Making it a table is making it worse, as that's not what tables do in R. Particularly if you want to use ggplot as your tags suggest, you need your data in a data.frame, which you can make like `smoke <- data.frame(NumberOfBooks = c(53,42,40,40,39,34,34,30,28,24,22,21,20,16), Grade = c('A','A','A','B','A','A','A','A','B','A','C','B','B', 'B'))`. It's still unclear how you want your graph structured from there, but that's at least the starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
smoke <- 

matrix(c(53,42,40,40,39,34,34,30,28,24,22,21,20,16,'A','A','A','B','A','A','A','A','B','A','C','B','B', 'B'),nrow=14, ncol = 2)
colnames(smoke) <- c("NumberofBooks","Grade")
smoke <- as.data.frame(smoke)

p <- ggplot(data = smoke, aes(y = NumberofBooks, x = Grade))
p <- (p
      + geom_bar(stat = 'Identity', position = 'dodge', color = 'white')
      )

print(p)
```

Not exactly sure what you're looking for, but this can get you started. You'll need to change to a data.frame to use ggplot

Comment: @AlexCabo Glad it helped. Please make sure to mark the question as solved and up vote for those that were helpful. All the best.

Comment: I added one additional piece in the code above `color = 'white'` that will help to differentiate your lines.

Comment: will do, can you just give me a brief explanation as to what you did after "p". I don't really know what aes is (or geom_bar for that matter).

Comment: Sure. aes is the aesthetics of the plot, so you define your x's and y's there. geom_bar is the type of plot (bar chart in your case, there are several other, I'd check the online documentation @ http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/ for more help with other types). position = 'dodge' separated out all your data, otherwise you would get a stacked bar chart, and the color will help isolate the lines. There's a lot you can do with ggplot, but this will hopefully get you started on where you want to go.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest way to put those values into a bar graph is just replacing matrix with data frame. Just like here:

```
number_of_books <- c(53,42,40,40,39,34,34,30,28,24,22,21,20,16)
grade <- c('A','A','A','B','A','A','A','A','B','A','C','B','B', 'B')
smoke <- data.frame(number_of_books,grade)

bar_graph <- ggplot(smoke, aes(number_of_books,grade)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: I think you have the x and y aesthetics backwards.

Comment: @AlexCabo you may have to install the package if you don't have it. Use `install.packages("ggplot2")` The answerer probably assumed that you do because of the `ggplot` tag on this question

Comment: @YangLi I thought I had installed ggplot2, I guess it didn't work.

Comment: @AlexCabo Just double check that you've loaded it with `library(ggplot2)`

Comment: @YangLi Yes, I did that. Seems to be working now, but it didn't print out a graph.

Comment: @AlexCabo in this case you still need to type `bar_graph` to display it because it's been stored in that... although as of now the answerer got the axis around the wrong way. With ggplot working you should try the other answers

Comment: @YangLi Thank you for being so patient and helpful. I'm quite new at this and have been taught close to nothing about it while still  being expected to use it1

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you are looking for?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# install.packages("dplyr"); install.packages("ggplot2")

smoke <- matrix(c(53,42,40,40,39,34,34,30,28,24,22,21,20,16,'A','A','A','B','A','A','A','    A','B','A','C','B','B', 'B'),nrow=14, ncol = 2)
colnames(smoke) <- c("NumberofBooks","Grade")

smoke %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  group_by(Grade) %>% 
  summarise(NumberofBooks = mean(as.numeric(NumberofBooks))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Grade, y = NumberofBooks)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  xlab("Grade") +
  ylab("Average Number of Books") +
  ggtitle("Average number of book by Grade")
```